# Any ideas on how to implement infinite scrolling on my Wordpress site?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, scroll, infinite

I am trying to implement infinite scrolling into my site at http://lastmealifetime.com/ and thus replace the downward arrow at the bottom of the page. However I am having some trouble.

I tried using this:

```
/**
 * Load javascripts used by the theme
 */

function custom_theme_js(){
    wp_register_script( 'infinite_scroll',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js', array('jquery'),null,true );
    if( ! is_singular() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('infinite_scroll');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_theme_js');

/**
 * Infinite Scroll
 */
function custom_infinite_scroll_js() {
    if( ! is_singular() ) { ?>
    <script>
    var infinite_scroll = {
        loading: {
            img: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif",
            msgText: "<?php _e( 'Loading the next set of posts...', 'custom' ); ?>",
            finishedMsg: "<?php _e( 'All posts loaded.', 'custom' ); ?>"
        },
        "nextSelector":"#nav-below .nav-previous a",
        "navSelector":"#nav-below",
        "itemSelector":"article",
        "contentSelector":"#content"
    };
    jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll );
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_infinite_scroll_js',100 );

/**
 * If we go beyond the last page and request a page that doesn't exist,
 * force WordPress to return a 404.
 * See http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15770
 */
function custom_paged_404_fix( ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( is_404() || !is_paged() || 0 != count( $wp_query->posts ) )
        return;

    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    nocache_headers();
}
add_action( 'wp', 'custom_paged_404_fix' );
```

However I am having trouble identifying the proper CSS selectors ("nextSelector","navSelector", "itemSelector", "contentSelector") for my particular theme.

Anyone have any suggestions on what I can do here?

Answer (score 0):

```
"nextSelector": ".load_more_cont",
"navSelector": ".load_more_cont a",
"itemSelector": ".home_post_box",
"contentSelector": "#load_posts_container"
```